# JQuery data selector not updating with .data

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

Basically if I have a div loaded onto a page with a `data-test` attribute and change the value of it with jquery's `.data('test')` I can no longer select the element with `$('div[data-test="newValue"]')`

```js
var howMany = $('.t[data-test="test"]').length;
$('.result').html('start there are ' + howMany + ' divs with data "test"<br /><br />');
setTimeout(function() {
  $('#one, #three').data('test', 'changed');
}, 500);
setTimeout(function() {
  var test = $('.t[data-test="test"]').length,
    changed = $('.t[data-test="changed"]').length;
  $('.result').append('there are ' + test + ' divs still with data "test"<br /><br />there are ' + changed + ' divs still with data "changed"<br /><br />');
}, 1000);
setTimeout(function() {
  $('.t').each(function() {
    $('.result').append('div #' + $(this).attr('id') + ' has the test data of: ' + $(this).data('test') + '<br /><br />');
  });
}, 1500);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="t" id="one" data-test="test">1</div>
<div class="t" id="two" data-test="test">2</div>
<div class="t" id="three" data-test="test">3</div>
<div class="t" id="four" data-test="test">4</div>
<div class="result"></div>
```

Comment: This might help http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/dataSelector

Answer (score 208, accepted):

jQuery .data() is initially populated with values from the `data-` attributes, but setting it only stores the associated new value in memory. It doesn't change the attribute in the DOM. To change the attribute, you have to use:

```
$('#one, #three').attr('data-test', 'changed');
```

The docs are at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/

Comment: Okay, so `.data` doesn't actually manipulate the DOM it just keeps the data in memory?

Comment: It can be used on any element and can store arbitrary data (not just strings). The only way it relates to the "data-" attributes is that for convenience it is automatically populated with these strings to begin with.

Comment: Normally, there's not a need for roundtripping .data()'s if you're consistent in using .data() to access/set/modify data on DOM elements.

Comment: WOW this was making me crazy.  I could test in chrome dev tools and see the value but look on the page and not see anything changed.  Very frustrating especially since the jquery docs say that you can make changes but do not mention this idiosyncrasy.

Comment: Who decided "setting it only stores the associated new value in memory. It doesn't change the attribute in the DOM."? That seems very strange functionality. Why not keep it updated.

Comment: This is a blessing-in-disguise. Earlier, I was worried that repeated calls to `.data()` were wasting time parsing JSON objects. If the DOM doesn't update, jQuery is likely taking advantages of some efficiencies related to that.

Comment: Not only that, after the cache has been initialized it won't go and update. So, for instance, if you make a call to `.data()` and then later set or change data attributes then future calls for `.data()` for the same element will not reflect these new values. Modified values will never be pulled into the cache and new values will not appear unless asked for by name `.data('foo')`.

Comment: .data() was working fine for me until I upgraded to jquery 3.x. I was using after the find function

Comment: I just got burned by that .data() not updating... tricky to debug. Er.. well I havent actually solved it yet, but I'm assuming if I write to the DOM it will solve the problem. Or actually maybe better yet is to not use the DOM and only use .data(). Dunno. But anyway, this info very helpful.

Answer (score 15):

That's because i think that `.data()` use a special cache object inside jQuery to store data (in fact you can evens store object or complex tipes of data), if you check all the attributes are unchanged. If you want to change the attribute, use `attr()`