# How to toggle data attribute with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to toggle between two possible values for a data attribute.

If `data-state` is equal to `enabled` then I want to change it to `disabled` and vice versa.

```
$('.sites .state').on('ajax:success', function(data, status, xhr) {
   var site = $(this).parents('article').first();

   if (site.data('state') == 'enabled') {
     site.attr('data-state', 'disabled');
   } else {
     site.attr('data-state', 'enabled');
   }
});
```

NOTE: I needed to change the DOM element and [to my knowledge](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9768213/147586), I can't use `data` to do that (hence the use of `attr`).

Comment: @VisioN See my update. I needed to change the DOM element and to my knowledge, I can't use data to do that (hence the use of attr).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
site.attr('data-state', 'disabled');
```

Should be

```
site.data('state', 'disabled');
```

When an element is created the `data-<value>` attribute can be used in initialize the data property, but after that you have to use the [jQuery.data()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) method to fetch or modify the data.

While `$(el).data('<data-name>')` returns the value, `$(el).data('<data-name>', value)` set the data value.

Updated: Based on the updated requirement

```
$('div').attr('data-state', $('div').attr('data-state') == 'enabled' ? 'disabled' : 'enabled')
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/cZta9/1/)

Comment: I needed to change the DOM element and to my knowledge, I can't use `data` to do that (hence the use of `attr`).

Answer (score 4):

Not really sure what the problem is, but since you are using `.data()` you might as well keep using it in your if/else. Doing `.attr('data-state')` saves it on the DOM element itself (visible when you inspect the element), while with `.data('state')` it is invisible, and also faster.

Also if you use the ternary operator you can make it into 1 small line:

```
site.attr('data-state', site.data('state') === 'enabled' 
    ? 'disabled' 
    : 'enabled');
```

Comment: I needed to change the DOM element and to my knowledge, I can't use data to do that (hence the use of attr).

Answer (score 3):

```
site.data('state', (site.data('state') == 'enabled' ? 'disabled' : 'enabled'))
```