# wizard using jquery eq() next and previous button

Tags: jquery, html

I have wizard like list with CURRENT item selected, including NEXT/PREVIOUS buttons, 
On clicking buttons I am updating data attribute so I can track current.

On clicking next its working fine, looks issue with my eq() in back button

```
<h1 data-index="3"></h1>
<ul>
  <li class="done">1</li>
  <li class="done">2</li>
  <li class="sel">3</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>

<a href="javascript:;" id="back">back</a>
<a href="javascript:;" id="next">next</a>
```

jQuery :

```
let i = $('h1').data('index');
$('h1').html(i);

$('#next').on('click', function(e){
  let i1 = $('h1').data('index');
  if (i1 < 4) {
    $('ul li').eq(i1).addClass('sel');
    $('ul li').eq(i1).prevAll().addClass('done');

    i1 ++;
    $('h1').data('index', i1);
    $('h1').html(i1);
  }
});
$('#back').on('click', function(e){
  let i2 = $('h1').data('index');
  alert('i2 : ' + i2);
  if (i2 > 1) {
    i2--;
    $('h1').data('index', i2);
    $('h1').html(i2);

    $('ul li').removeClass('sel');
    $('ul li').eq(i2).addClass('sel');
    $('ul li').eq(i2).nextAll().removeClass('done');
    //$('ul li').eq(i2).nextAll().removeClass('done sel');
  }
});
```

here is link for jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/mawLnqq0/

Comment: The `data-index` attribute will not be updated unless you set it directly with `$('h1').attr('data-index', i1);`. http://stackoverflow.com/q/9768165/3168107

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your classes are conflicting in the back button,
You need to remove the `done` class when adding the `sel` class in the `<li>`.
Also `eq()` index starts from 0 , hence the `(i2-1)`.

Try this code for the back button click

```
$('#back').on('click', function(e){
  let i2 = $('h1').data('index');
  alert('i2 : ' + i2);
  if (i2 > 1) {
    i2--;
    $('h1').data('index', i2);
    $('h1').html(i2);

    $('ul li').removeClass('sel');
    $('ul li').eq((i2-1)).removeClass('done').addClass('sel');
    $('ul li').eq((i2-1)).nextAll().removeClass('done');
    //$('ul li').eq(i2).nextAll().removeClass('done sel');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried to fix your code. I posting my version of solution of your problem. Here's a **[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mawLnqq0/5/)**

```
let index = 3;
$('#back').on('click', function(e) {
  let $current = $('.sel');
  if ($current.prev('li').length) {
      $current.removeClass('sel').prev('li').removeClass('done').addClass('sel');
      index--;
  }
  updateIndex();
});

function updateIndex() {
  $('h1').data('index', index).text(index);
}
```

```js
let index = 3;
updateIndex();
$('#next').on('click', function(e) {
  let $current = $('.sel');
  if ($current.next('li').length) {
    $current.removeClass('sel').addClass('done').next('li').addClass('sel');
    index++;
  }
  updateIndex();
});
$('#back').on('click', function(e) {
  let $current = $('.sel');
  if ($current.prev('li').length) {
    $current.removeClass('sel').prev('li').removeClass('done').addClass('sel');
    index--;
  }
  updateIndex();
});

function updateIndex() {
  $('h1').data('index', index).text(index);
}
```

```css
ul li {
  color: #333;
  font-size: 14px;
}

ul li.sel {
  color: red;
  font-size: 22px;
}

ul li.done {
  color: green;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 data-index="3"></h1>
<ul>
  <li class="done">1</li>
  <li class="done">2</li>
  <li class="sel">3</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>

<a href="javascript:;" id="back">back</a>
<a href="javascript:;" id="next">next</a>
```