# Change value of data-src of <a> element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is code of form in my View:

```
 <form class="step_1_hotel_form item_loaded" data-price="9696" data-price_per_pax="4848" data-price_part="443.52041928" action="/search/check/790115838" accept-charset="UTF-8" data-remote="true" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">
  <div class="hotel_result">
    <div class="image_wrap">
      <a class="fancybox_82763 thumb_a" href="https://aobtravel.s3.amazonaws.com/hotelpictures/007/062/904/STO-QUA1-1.jpg?1485853861" data-fancybox="gallery">
        <div class="image">
          <div class="resize-and-crop" style="width: 250px; height: 200px;"><img alt="Exteriör" src="https://aobtravel.s3.amazonaws.com/hotelpictures/007/062/904/STO-QUA1-1.jpg?1485853861" width="250" height="353" class="big_thumb" style="left: 0px; top: -77px;"></div>
        </div>
      </a>

      <div class="other_images">
          <div class="small_image">
            <a class="fancybox_82763" href="https://aobtravel.s3.amazonaws.com/hotelpictures/007/062/904/STO-QUA1-1.jpg?1485853861" data-fancybox="gallery">
              <div class="resize-and-crop" style="width: 60px; height: 40px;"><img alt="Exteriör" src="https://aobtravel.s3.amazonaws.com/hotelpictures/007/062/904/STO-QUA1-1.jpg?1485853861" width="60" height="85" class="small_thumb_img" style="left: 0px; top: -23px;"></div>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="small_image">
            <a class="fancybox_82763" href="https://aobtravel.s3.amazonaws.com/hotelpictures/007/062/906/STO-QUA1-2.jpg?1485853861" data-fancybox="gallery">
              <div class="resize-and-crop" style="width: 60px; height: 40px;"><img alt="Exteriör" src="https://aobtravel.s3.amazonaws.com/hotelpictures/007/062/906/STO-QUA1-2.jpg?1485853861" width="60" height="40" class="small_thumb_img" style="left: 0px; top: 0px;"></div>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="small_image">
            <a class="fancybox_82763" href="https://aobtravel.s3.amazonaws.com/hotelpictures/007/062/907/STO-QUA1-3.jpg?1485853861" data-fancybox="gallery">
              <div class="resize-and-crop" style="width: 60px; height: 40px;"><img alt="Gästrum" src="https://aobtravel.s3.amazonaws.com/hotelpictures/007/062/907/STO-QUA1-3.jpg?1485853861" width="73" height="40" class="small_thumb_img" style="left: -7px; top: 0px;"></div>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="small_image">
            <a class="fancybox_82763" href="https://aobtravel.s3.amazonaws.com/hotelpictures/007/062/909/STO-QUA1-4.jpg?1485853862" data-fancybox="gallery">
              <div class="resize-and-crop" style="width: 60px; height: 40px;"><img alt="Gästrum" src="https://aobtravel.s3.amazonaws.com/hotelpictures/007/062/909/STO-QUA1-4.jpg?1485853862" width="60" height="41" class="small_thumb_img" style="left: 0px; top: -1px;"></div>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="small_image">
            <a class="fancybox_82763" href="https://aobtravel.s3.amazonaws.com/hotelpictures/007/062/911/STO-QUA1-5.jpg?1485853862" data-fancybox="gallery">
              <div class="resize-and-crop" style="width: 60px; height: 40px;"><img alt="Gästrum" src="https://aobtravel.s3.amazonaws.com/hotelpictures/007/062/911/STO-QUA1-5.jpg?1485853862" width="60" height="40" class="small_thumb_img" style="left: 0px; top: 0px;"></div>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="small_image">
            <a class="fancybox_82763" href="https://aobtravel.s3.amazonaws.com/hotelpictures/007/062/913/STO-QUA1-6.jpg?1485853862" data-fancybox="gallery">
              <div class="resize-and-crop" style="width: 60px; height: 40px;"><img alt="Restaurang" src="https://aobtravel.s3.amazonaws.com/hotelpictures/007/062/913/STO-QUA1-6.jpg?1485853862" width="60" height="40" class="small_thumb_img" style="left: 0px; top: 0px;"></div>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="small_image">
            <a class="fancybox_82763" href="https://aobtravel.s3.amazonaws.com/hotelpictures/007/062/916/STO-QUA1-7.jpg?1485853862" data-fancybox="gallery">
              <div class="resize-and-crop" style="width: 60px; height: 40px;"><img alt="Bar/Lounge" src="https://aobtravel.s3.amazonaws.com/hotelpictures/007/062/916/STO-QUA1-7.jpg?1485853862" width="60" height="40" class="small_thumb_img" style="left: 0px; top: 0px;"></div>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="small_image">
            <a class="fancybox_82763" href="https://aobtravel.s3.amazonaws.com/hotelpictures/007/062/917/STO-QUA1-8.jpg?1485853863" data-fancybox="gallery">
              <div class="resize-and-crop" style="width: 60px; height: 40px;"><img alt="Konferensrum" src="https://aobtravel.s3.amazonaws.com/hotelpictures/007/062/917/STO-QUA1-8.jpg?1485853863" width="60" height="40" class="small_thumb_img" style="left: 0px; top: 0px;"></div>
            </a>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="information">
      <div class="name_group">
        <div class="name">Scandic Prince Philip</div>
        <div class="rating">
            <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dzwdseno3/image/asset/f_auto/star-bb0cd011d3d4aa12c83109f30c6c17ed.png" alt="Star">
            <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dzwdseno3/image/asset/f_auto/star-bb0cd011d3d4aa12c83109f30c6c17ed.png" alt="Star">
            <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dzwdseno3/image/asset/f_auto/star-bb0cd011d3d4aa12c83109f30c6c17ed.png" alt="Star">
        </div>
        <div class="address">
          <a class=" fancybox" href="javascript:;" data-type="ajax" data-src="/hotel_map/82763" data-options="{&quot;touch&quot;:false,&quot;baseClass&quot;:null}">
            Oxholmsgr 2 Kungens Kurva, Po Box 6084<img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dzwdseno3/image/asset/map_view-94e4f080f570d6f5e53d0ca291ce82de.png" alt="Map view">
</a>        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="price-box-hotel">
          <div class="resurs">
            <a class=" fancybox" href="javascript:;" data-type="ajax" data-src="/payment/annuity_description/969600" data-options="{&quot;touch&quot;:false,&quot;baseClass&quot;:null}">
              <div class="resurs_text">Delbetala fr.</div>
              <div class="resurs_price">887 kr</div>
</a>          </div>

        <div class="pax-price">
          <div class="price">4.848 kr</div>
          <div class="smallprice">per person</div>
        </div>

        <div class="total-price">
          <div class="price">9.696 kr</div>
            <div class="smallprice">totalt</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="hotel_clear"></div>
      <div class="description">

        This hotel is located close to Skarholmens Metro station with a 25 min metro ride into Central Station. It is also easily reached by car, being located just off the E3/E4 roads. Car journey ... <a class=" fancybox" href="javascript:;" data-type="ajax" data-src="/hotel_info/82763" data-options="{&quot;touch&quot;:false,&quot;baseClass&quot;:null}">Läs mer</a>
      </div>


      <div class="rooms">
          <div class="room">
            <div class="headline">Rum 1 <div class="pax-text">(2 vuxna)</div></div>
            <div class="options">
                <ul class="table selected_hotel">
                  <li class="radio">
                    <input type="radio" name="hr_82763_1" id="hr_82763_1_cb157e721df4a40e988e0b29e158c9c3" value="cb157e721df4a40e988e0b29e158c9c3" data-price="0" data-price_per_pax="0" data-price_part="443.52041928" checked="checked">
                  </li>
                  <div class="table_div">
                    <li class="li_1">Standard Twin FLEX</li>
                    <li class="li_2">Inkl frukost</li>
                    <li class="li_3">+0 kr</li>
                  </div>
                </ul>
                <ul class="table ">
                  <li class="radio">
                    <input type="radio" name="hr_82763_1" id="hr_82763_1_d0b4d600dceac223ca4fe5dde5985fa1" value="d0b4d600dceac223ca4fe5dde5985fa1" data-price="1216" data-price_per_pax="608" data-price_part="499.14344216">
                  </li>
                  <div class="table_div">
                    <li class="li_1">Standard Twin Non-refundable EARLY1</li>
                    <li class="li_2">Inkl frukost</li>
                    <li class="li_3">+1.216 kr</li>
                  </div>
                </ul>
                <ul class="table ">
                  <li class="radio">
                    <input type="radio" name="hr_82763_1" id="hr_82763_1_0ecb5bab8a7642a44468d666b584c25f" value="0ecb5bab8a7642a44468d666b584c25f" data-price="2064" data-price_per_pax="1032" data-price_part="537.9331817999999">
                  </li>
                  <div class="table_div">
                    <li class="li_1">Family Room FLEX</li>
                    <li class="li_2">Inkl frukost</li>
                    <li class="li_3">+2.064 kr</li>
                  </div>
                </ul>
                <ul class="table ">
                  <li class="radio">
                    <input type="radio" name="hr_82763_1" id="hr_82763_1_41858d0c8cc554bf3201a40304c7c81a" value="41858d0c8cc554bf3201a40304c7c81a" data-price="2774" data-price_per_pax="1387" data-price_part="570.410440225">
                  </li>
                  <div class="table_div">
                    <li class="li_1">Standard Plus Twin Room Non-refundable EARLY1</li>
                    <li class="li_2">Inkl frukost</li>
                    <li class="li_3">+2.774 kr</li>
                  </div>
                </ul>
                <ul class="table ">
                  <li class="radio">
                    <input type="radio" name="hr_82763_1" id="hr_82763_1_c6593fc2f12e74897483a779543d3826" value="c6593fc2f12e74897483a779543d3826" data-price="3113" data-price_per_pax="1556" data-price_part="585.9171875575">
                  </li>
                  <div class="table_div">
                    <li class="li_1">Standard Plus Twin Room FLEX</li>
                    <li class="li_2">Inkl frukost</li>
                    <li class="li_3">+3.113 kr</li>
                  </div>
                </ul>
                <ul class="table ">
                  <li class="radio">
                    <input type="radio" name="hr_82763_1" id="hr_82763_1_d47c331e387d6758cf707f34a3349256" value="d47c331e387d6758cf707f34a3349256" data-price="3221" data-price_per_pax="1610" data-price_part="590.8573902475">
                  </li>
                  <div class="table_div">
                    <li class="li_1">Family Room Non-refundable EARLY1</li>
                    <li class="li_2">Inkl frukost</li>
                    <li class="li_3">+3.221 kr</li>
                  </div>
                </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>

      <div class="continue-button-hotel">
          <div class="spinner" id="step_1_82763_spinner" style="display: none;"><img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dzwdseno3/image/asset/ajax-loader_white-c5cd7f5300576ab4c88202b42f6ded62.gif" alt="Ajax loader white"></div>
            <div class="y-button"><input type="submit" name="commit" value="Välj hotell: 9.696 kr" class="hotel" data-disable-with="Välj hotell: 9.696 kr"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

I need to change data-src on clicking radio in that form

Here is what I tried:

```
 $('.step_1_hotel_form:not(.item_loaded)').find('input[type=radio]').on('change', function() {
  $('.table', $(this).form).removeClass('selected_hotel');
  $('input[type=radio]:checked').closest('ul').addClass('selected_hotel');
  update_price_on_button_hotel($(this).closest('form'));


});
```

And Below is `update_price_on_button_hotel` function

```
 export function update_price_on_button_hotel(form): void {

    Helpers.set_currency_settings();

    let price_part, price_per_pax;
    let price = parseFloat(form.attr('data-price'));
    if (form.attr('data-price_per_pax')) { price_per_pax = parseFloat(form.attr('data-price_per_pax')); }
    if (form.attr('data-price_part')) { price_part = parseFloat(form.attr('data-price_part')); }

    if ($('.step_1_air_form').length > 0) {
      $('input[type=checkbox]:checked', $('.step_1_air_form')[0]).each(function() {
        price += parseFloat($(this).attr('data-price'));
        if ($(this).attr('data-price_per_pax')) { price_per_pax += parseFloat($(this).attr('data-price_per_pax')); }
        if ($(this).attr('data-price_part')) { price_part += parseFloat($(this).attr('data-price_part')); }
      });
    }

    $('.room', form).each(function() {
      const input = $(this).find('input[type=radio]:checked');
      price += parseFloat(input.attr('data-price'));
      if (input.attr('data-price_per_pax')) { price_per_pax += parseFloat(input.attr('data-price_per_pax')); }
      if (input.attr('data-price_part')) { price_part += parseFloat(input.attr('data-price_part')); }
    });

    form.find('input[type=submit]').each(function() {
      if ($(this).val() !== '') {
        $(this).val(($(this).val() as string ).split(':')[0] + ": " + accounting.formatMoney(price));
      } else {
        $(this).val(accounting.formatMoney(price));
      }
    });

    form.find('.total-price .price').html(accounting.formatMoney(price));
    if (form.attr('data-price_per_pax')) { form.find('.pax-price .price').html(accounting.formatMoney(price_per_pax)); }
    if (form.attr('data-price_part') && (price_part > 0) && (form.find('.resurs .resurs_price').length > 0)) {
      form.find('.resurs .resurs_price').html(accounting.formatMoney(price_part));
    }

  }
}
```

I wantto find  element and change it data-src value.

So I tried to do it like this

> form.find('.fancybox').data('src','/payment/annuity_description/1');

But it is not working

Comment: try `form.find('.fancybox').attr('data-src','/payment/annuity_description/1');`

Comment: yes. Thank's it works @CarstenLøvboAndersen

Comment: "But it not works" - how are you determining whether it has worked or not?   `.data(name, value)` does not update the HTML, it updates the internal dictionary held in memory.  Have you tried `console.log(form.find(".fancybox').data("src")`? which is how you access data attributes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JQuery data selector not updating with .data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9768165/jquery-data-selector-not-updating-with-data)