# trying to update the data elements using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I had the code running where i am trying to replace some value using jquery

here is my button

```
<button data-class="update" type="button" name="update" class="action" data-pk="RS" 
        id="update" data-columns="RRC,TTR,N">Create</button>
```

i have this code where onclick on the radio button, i want to update the data attribute where data-pk will be replaced with one of the values from data-columns and data-pk value will get added to data-columns

so kind of adding value to one attribute and vice versa

the data-columns is a list, so that is where i am getting stuck

```
$('input[name="primarykey"]').click(function() {
  $("#action").data('pk',$(this).val());
});
```

i can add this value which will overwrite the other existing value, but i want to copy that value and add it to the `data-columns` and remove that value from the data-columns which will be added to this `data-pk`

Comment: Your button `id` is `update`, not `action`

Comment: Any clue to the structure of your data-columns will be useful in giving you a good answer. A simple html snippet might help

Answer (score 0):

Couple things:

1. Your trying to access `action` as an `id` (`#`), you would have to set an `id` attribute for the element.
2. Using `.data()` will not update the DOM for you (src: [JQuery data selector not updating with .data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9768165/jquery-data-selector-not-updating-with-data))

   > jQuery .data() is initially populated with values from the data- attributes but setting it only stores the associated new value in memory. It doesn't change the attribute in the DOM. To change the attribute, you have to use:
3. By using `.attr()` you may alter the DOM and change the value of `data-pk` and `data-columns`.

```js
let el = $('#action');
const options = $.map($('input[name="primarykey"]'), e => e.value);

$('input[name="primarykey"]').click(function() {
  el.attr('data-pk', $(this).val());
  el.attr('data-columns', options.filter(e => e !== $(this).val()));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button data-class="update" type="button" name="update" id="action" data-pk="RS" id="update" data-columns="RRC,TTR,N">Create</button>

<input type='radio' name='primarykey' value='RRC'>
<input type='radio' name='primarykey' value='TTR'>
<input type='radio' name='primarykey' value='N'>
<input type='radio' name='primarykey' value='RS' checked>
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: trying to use `let el = $('button[data-class="update"]');` - but it did not work, that is the common link i can find

Comment: @Seb could you please update your question to include the relevant HTML and JS (the input radios and buttons) so I could be a little more thorough with my answer

Comment: That is the html of the button i had in a page to do it, there is no extra code, your code is right, but my usecase is can i use the data attribute in the el to make sure it works

Comment: when i initially load my page, no radio is checked, and when i click, it gives me undefined

Comment: what are the `value`'s of the radio buttons? are they `RRC`,`TTR`,`N` and `RS`?

Comment: yes, they are correct, i am confused, that even i ran your code in the fiddle , it works https://jsfiddle.net/p45Lt8gn/
i am also using same code but why it seems not working on my site, is there any other way i can try, appreciated response

Comment: I need to see your radio inputs to help further. Also, did you update the 'Create' button to use `id` as opposed to class (`id="action"`)?

Comment: i see, its hidden inside the tab and that tab is clicked and then it loads

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197530/discussion-between-seb-and-miroslav-glamuzina).