# I want to dynamically change value of my button from a form input filled by the user using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, forms, button

A user fills a form (to customize a product), and I want to take their output to dynamically change info of my button.

I've succeed to fetch what the user fills in the form, but I can't succeed to change the value in my button.

*My form:*

```
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Selecting elements</legend>
        <p>
            <label>Select type : </label>
            <select id="type" name="type">
                <option> X </option>
                <option> Palleitte </option>
            </select>
        </p>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

*My button:*

```
<button name="julien" class="snipcart-add-item" id="my-button"
        data-item-id="{{ product.identifier }}"
        data-item-name="{{ product.name }}"
        data-item-price="20.00"
        data-item-custom2-name="Type"
        data-item-custom2-options="Cachet|Palleitte"
        data-item-custom2-value=""
        data-item-custom3-name="Quantité"
        data-item-custom3-options="100g|200g|500g|1kg|100kg"
        data-item-custom3-value="500g">
    ADD TO THE CART 
</button>
```

*My jQuery code:*

```
$('#weight').change(function() {
    $('#my-button').data('item-custom3-value', $(this).val());
    console.log($('#my-button').data('item-custom3-value', $(this).val()));
    console.log($(this).val());
});
```

I expect to change the value of my button: `data-item-custom2-value=""` by the value of what the user filled in the form, thanks in advance!

Comment: `I've succeed to fetch somehow what the user fill in the form` can you elaborate where are you fetching the user filled entry?

Comment: Where's the element `$('#weight')`?

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9768165/jquery-data-selector-not-updating-with-data jQuery's `data()` method doesn't set attribute values.

Comment: Yeah really sorry I got confused in my code and I just wanted to extract the most important but I copy pasted the wrong one..... For this HTML form my Jquery code would be :                                                                                                                                     ```   $('#type').change(function() {
      $('#my-button').data('item-custom2-value', $(this).val());
      console.log($(this).val());
  }); ```

Comment: It's okey working, thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

Line of code to change to make it work :

```
    console.log($('#my-button').attr('data-item-custom3-value', $(this).val()));
```

More general answer :

```
    console.log($('#id-you-target').attr('element-you-want-to-target', $(this).val()));
```

Hope it will  help you  !