# Html attribute value update but return first value all time as garbage

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, garbage-collection, garbage

I am trying to set attribute for a Html label I am setting its value by jQuery on every change but when I try to get attribute value it return value first value that was assign to this attribute. Here are some code chunks for better understanding

```
<label class="" id="totalShortHours" name="totalShortHours">0</label>
```

On every change in time field it change attribute value that I can check in Developer tools element

[image]

But When I try to get value it return garbage

[image]

Comment: user `$('#totalShortHours').attr('data-hours');`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9768213/5104748 may help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `document.getElementById('totalShortHours').dataset.hours` will resolve your issue.